# Need to understand where to update custom price when order create from admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-order-create

I need to update custom product attribute values the same as custom price and qty update. When an order is created from the admin. If anyone has an idea, please help me.

please check the below image

[image]

I need the updated value of `Opslag Marge` when adding value on the Opslag edit box and click on the `Update Items and Qty's` button

I have checked sales.js `productConfigureSubmit : function(listType, area, fieldsPrepare, itemsFilter)` and also check `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` but not understand how can update custom price on order create in admin.

Comment: I have the same question if anyone has an answer plz help??

Comment: @BhavinGohil if you get any answers related to this post please post here. it's helpful to me Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to get a solution from sales.js which is located at `js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js`. in that file, I have to find `productConfigureSubmit` that is saved and put data when pressing the `Update Items and Qty's` button.

> ```
> productConfigureSubmit : function(listType, area, fieldsPrepare, itemsFilter) {
>     area = this.prepareArea(area);
>     this.loadingAreas = area;
>     var url = this.loadBaseUrl + 'block/' + area + '?isAjax=true';
>
>     // prepare additional fields
>     fieldsPrepare = this.prepareParams(fieldsPrepare);
>     fieldsPrepare.reset_shipping = 1;
>     fieldsPrepare.json = 1;
>
>     // create fields
>     var fields = [];
>    for (var name in fieldsPrepare) {
>        fields.push(new Element('input', {type: 'hidden', name: name, value: fieldsPrepare[name]}));
>    }
>    productConfigure.addFields(fields);
>
>    // filter items
>    if (itemsFilter) {
>        productConfigure.addItemsFilter(listType, itemsFilter);
>    }
>
>    // prepare and do submit
>    productConfigure.addListType(listType, {urlSubmit: url});
>    productConfigure.setOnLoadIFrameCallback(listType, function(response){
>        this.loadAreaResponseHandler(response);
>    }.bind(this));
>    productConfigure.submit(listType);
>    // clean
>    this.productConfigureAddFields = {};
>    },
> ```